# bypassing @Test dependsOnMethods due to failure

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have a question regarding the @Test(dependOnMethods{""})..
I want my tests to run in a particular order so I hit every test that I have written. The best way to do this so far, atleast that I have found, is the dependsOnMethods! However, since the tests to come after requires the one before it to pass, I cant run all of my tests and see which ones failed. My program just exits! So here is what I'm working with..

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"shouldSelectAmountOfDoors"})
public void shouldSelectExtColor() throws InterruptedException{
    sycOptionalInfoPage.selectExtColor("GREEN");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"shouldSelectExtColor"})
public void shouldSelectIntColor() throws InterruptedException{
    sycOptionalInfoPage.selectIntColor("GOLD");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"shouldSelectIntColor"})
public void shouldEnterAComment() throws InterruptedException{
    sycOptionalInfoPage.enterComments("<(*-<)  <(*-*)>  (>-*)>   woot!");
    takeABreakYo();
}
```

Boom. Very easy to understand and trusty POM! But, if my shouldSelectIntColor() fails due to a changed id from the dev team, I want the shouldEnterAComment to still run! How can I continue to keep my tests chained in a line, but still run after a failure? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you saying you want your tests to be in a fixed order? Why? Do they depend on each other? That would be bad test design.

Comment: Heres the thing, the tests jump around right? So I have a test that presses the next button to get to the next page. I dont want that test to run before I attempt to dive into the other options on the page. So yes, I would prefer them to be in a fixed order.

Comment: In that case wouldn't it mean that if the test to go to the next page fails, you shouldn't run the tests for the options on that page? Can't you let all those tests depend on the 'next' test and let their order be random?

Comment: Im sorry, I feel as if you are understanding something that I am not. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I just re-read you comment and I am mistaken, my bad. I see you already have the solution. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `priority` instead of `dependsOnMethods` to achieve what you want:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void shouldSelectIntColor() throws InterruptedException{
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void shouldEnterAComment() throws InterruptedException{
}
```

Here if your `shouldSelectIntColor` method fails, it will still execute `shouldEnterAComment` test method.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use priority as mentioned or you can use `run-always=true`. Its called soft dependancy. This way your methods will still run even if the method before failed.